# ¿Es posible crear una lista constante, de un string especificando sus dimensiones?

Tags: python, lista

Debo concatenar una tabla de 5xn, con una valor en especifico que corresponde a un número de documento, es decir, quiero tener la tabla con una columna al final que sea n veces el número de documento.
¿Cómo vuelvo este número de documento una columna de n filas, para poderla concatenar con la matriz posteriormente?
Busco algo así como la función np.zeros, pero en este caso con un string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre algo como la función `repeat` de `numpy`:

```
x = np.array(["A"])
list(np.repeat(x, 7,axis=0))
```

Devolviendo como resultado:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A']
```

Espero te sirva! Saludos!